# Merge Sort and Queue

Tags: c++, unix, stack, queue, mergesort

Im working on a review sheet pretty much got everything except not sure about these two. any help please?

Q what is the benefit of using a queue to do merge sort?
Q suppose in mergesort we replace the queue with a stack
(i.e. push instead of enqueue, pop in place of dequeue).
explain what effect this replacement will have.

Answer (score 0):

With `queues` things automatically are added to the end of the list; thus, when you get to the lowest level of `mergesort`'s recursion (individual elements), your sorted array can just `enqueue` the largest of these elements into a new list. Using a `stack` should reverse your list since all elements added will be put at the front, so you'd have to essentially search for the smallest element instead of the largest.